# What's the difference between $(\mathbb Z_n,+)$ and $(\mathbb Z_n,*)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

I noticed that $(\mathbb Z_n,+)$ and $(\mathbb Z_n,*)$ are not the same thing. For example 2 is not invertible in $(\mathbb Z_6,*)$. However, since $\bar2+\bar4=\bar0$, thus it is invertible in  $(\mathbb Z_6,+)$.

I found the following problems:

1. Am I right? If so, why does any book not mention this difference which is very important?
2. When we study groups, what's the standard operation of $\mathbb Z_n$ when the operation is omitted?
3. When we study rings, do we generally use $(\mathbb Z_n,+)$ to be the abelian group of the ring $(\mathbb Z_n,+,*)$?
4. If I work with $(\mathbb Z_n,+)$ I would lose these theorems which I proved for $(\mathbb Z_n,*)$?

> - An element $a$ in $(\mathbb Z_n,*)$ is an unit iff $a$ and $n$ are  coprimes
> - An element $a$ in $(\mathbb Z_n,*)$ is an zero divisor iff $a$ and
>     $n$ aren't coprimes

I'm sure there are a lot of student with this same doubt.

I really need help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Since $(\Bbb Z_n,\cdot)$ is not a group, it's usually addition.

Comment: @AsafKaragila ha yes, of course, thank you

Comment: $(\mathbb Z_n,*)$ may not be a group but it is an interesting monoid. Try determining zero divisors and niltpotent elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Usually, $\,(\Bbb Z_n\,,\,+)\;$ would represent an additive cyclic group, which elements are usually represented as $\,\{\overline0\,,\,\overline 1\,\ldots\,\overline{n-1}\}\;$ or as $\,\{0,1,2,...,n-1\}\pmod n\,$ .

The set $\,(\Bbb Z_n\,,\,+\,,\,\cdot)\,$ represents the ring of residues modulo $\,n\,$ , with the same addition as above and multiplication modulo $\,n\,$ .

The set of invertible elements in the above ring is usually denoted by $\,\Bbb Z_n^*\;$, and sometimes $\,(\Bbb Z_n^*,\cdot)\;$ , and it is the set of elements in $\,\{0,1,2,...,n-1\}\pmod n\,$ which are coprime with $\,n\,$ (and non-zero, to avoid problems). This is a group under the usual multiplication in the above ring.

Of course, what you prove for a set under some operation may, and may **not**, be true for the same set, or a subset, under a different operation. Perhaps it'll be good you tell us what things were you thinking about.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $(Z_{n}, *)$ is just the set $Z_{n}$ and a binary operation multiplication modulo $n$. Yes, you are right, this is entirely different from $(Z_{n}, +)$. The reason the books will not mention it because the former is not a group and hence not discussed, but nobody will say that they are the same things.

Comment: If I work with $(Z_n,+)$ I will lose the theorems I proved to $(Z_n,*)$?

Comment: Yes you will, but what theorems could you prove for the multiplication structure? In fact the additive group in question is the simplest group you will encounter in your life, proving theorems about it are not hard at all.

Answer (score 1):

$(\mathbb Z_n,+)$ is cyclic. It is a regular polygon in the euclidian plane.

$(\mathbb Z_n,*)$ is a much complicated thing that makes the wonders of great mathematicians (Pythagoras, Gauss, Euler,...).

Comment: You mean, a regular polygon under rotations only. When you add reflections, you get a different group.