# Show that $\overline{x}\in\Bbb Z/(n\Bbb Z)$ is invertible iff $\gcd(x,n)=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Be $n$ greater than 2 integer and is $\bar x\in\mathbb{Z}_n-\{\bar0,\bar1,\bar2,\ldots,\overline{n-1}\},$ $\;0\leq x<n$. Show that $\exists\; \bar y\in\mathbb{Z}_n$, such that $\bar x\cdot \bar y=\bar y\cdot \bar x=\bar1\Longleftrightarrow gcd\{x,n\}=1$ (i.e., the elements $\bar x$, $0\leq x<n$, invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ são aqueles tais que $gcd\{x,n\}=1$)

Comment: What is your $\;\Bbb Z_n\;$ ?

Comment: It is discussed here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/406560/whats-the-difference-between-mathbb-z-n-and-mathbb-z-n.

Comment: 'overline' instead of 'bar'

Comment: @drhab Ah yes, it worked, as edited, thanks.

Comment: Zev's answer at the linked duplicate is a great explanation of this.

Answer (score 1):

By the [Bézout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_identity):

$$\gcd(x,n)=1\iff \exists y,t\in\Bbb Z,\; yx+tn=1\iff\exists \overline y\in\Bbb Z_n,\; \overline y\overline x=\overline1$$

Comment: You're missing an existential quantifier in the final equation.